# Click on one DataField in gridview will open a new grid view

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

My Target:
I have one gridview on the asp page now the first column is showing some numbers (which is primary key in SQL)
Now I want if someone clicks on any of the number he should be navigated to a new page where he can edit the fields connected to the number clicked.

Note: in the first grid view I have not selected all the columns from sql but in the editing page i want most of the columns from database.

[image]

Comment: how to ask a good question? answer: [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Broad ask. Guess you added right tag asp.net but you mentioned asp page.

Add hyperlink in the id column of gridview to navigate to edit page with Primary key value as querystring.

In pageload of editing page, read the querystring & query all the Columns of record you need using id, edit & update the DB. At the end response.redirect to grid page.